# Portion of PHP code doesn't catch anything

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML text like this:

```
<span class="label">ITCAM for AD/WebSphere/J2EE</span> (26)
    <ul>
        <li class="server"><span class="label">ADLIVECYCES2-P1</span></li>
        <li class="server"><span class="label">ADLIVECYCES2-P2</span></li>
        <li class="server"><span class="label">J168-L168</span></li>
        <li class="server"><span class="label">WAS linux webapplication</span></li>
        <li class="server"><span class="label">WAS linux webservice</span></li>
        <li class="server"><span class="label">WAS windows Adobe2</span></li>
        <li class="server"><span class="label">WASzos linux webservice</span></li>
        <li class="server"><span class="label">lhewbawas01</span></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="callerType">
```

I want catch the class label in order to put into an array all the server name (ADLIVECYCES2-P1 until to lhewbswas01) in server class and then label class.
To do this I tried to write down a simple PHP code as following:

```
<?php

 include('C:\Manutenzione\Analisi_TT\simple_html_dom.php');

$ip_soatt04='myIP';

$usr_soatt = 'root';
$pwd_soatt = 'mypwd';
$dom = new DomDocument();
    
    $connection_soatt04 = ssh2_connect($ip_soatt04, 22);
    
    if (!$connection_soatt04)
    {
        echo "impossibile connettersi a soatt04";
    }
        
    ssh2_auth_password($connection_soatt04, $usr_soatt , $pwd_soatt);
    
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection_soatt04,'cat /opt/sw/db_viewer/todata_summary.html');
    
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    
    $stream_out=stream_get_contents($stream);

    $dom->loadHTML($stream_out);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
    
    $heading=parseToArray($xpath,'server');
    
function parseToArray($xpath,$class)
{
    $xpathquery="//li[@class='".$class."']/span";
    $elements = $xpath->query($xpathquery);
    

    if (!is_null($elements)) {  
        $resultarray=array();
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            $nodes = $element->childNodes;
            foreach ($nodes as $node) {
              $resultarray[] = $node->nodeValue;
            }
        }
        return $resultarray;
    }
}

    
            
?>
```

But $resultarray variable is empty.
What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Have you confirmed that `$stream_out` is populated with the HTML you were expecting?

Comment: @Rob Eyre If I write echo $stream_out; in the script I get the html I need to parse

Comment: The next thing to check would be your XPath expression then.  Have you checked `$elements` has multiple elements, and that each one is a `<span>` element?  (NB you don't need to iterate through child text nodes, you should just be able to call `$element->nodeValue` to get the text content of the span)

Comment: I checked and I get what I want into $heading variable. But since html is bigger the script catches other strings. I'd like to catch only the servers list under "ITCAM for AD/WebSphere/J2EE" only. How should I do?

Comment: You could try an XPath expression like `//span[@class="label"][.='ITCAM for AD/WebSphere/J2EE']/following-sibling::ul/li[@class="server"]/span[@class="label"]'` - that basically looks for the label and then returns span elements from the list that follows it